# PHP Echo Also Outoug images alt Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am outputting the `alt` attribute in

```
 echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_link($image, 'large').'" alt="Projects" />';
```

in following snippet:

```
$images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true);
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">';
    echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
      echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_link($image, 'large').'" alt="Projects" />';
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

here is what happening

[image]

Comment: What your `wp_get_attachment_link($image, 'large')` prints? Add the screenshot of inspect element.

Comment: Most likely this is the result of an attempt of the browser to fix a broken html markup. Most likely the markup you send out is broken by tokens inside the return value of the call to `wp_get_attachment_link()`. So dump it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Look at the raw HTML that's being output by this...

Comment: Not familiar with WP but looks like that function returns an HTML link, which close your `img` before you expect so the other content outputs as text. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_link/

Comment: Must need a `wordpress` tag..... The issue is of wordpress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_link` returns an `html link` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link
Use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` instead https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

```
$images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true);
foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <?php 
            $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image,'large');
            if ($img && isset($img[0])):
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $img[0];?>" alt="Projects" />
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY LIKE THIS

```
echo "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_image_src($image,'large')."' alt='Projects'/>";
```

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src returns array of 4 elements. Url, width, height and is_intermediate(generated or original).

Answer (score 0):

error in this line

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_link($image, 'large').'" alt="Projects" />';
```

Your error are due to `'` in `'large'` change to below

```
$images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true);
foreach ($images as $image) {?>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="<?=wp_get_attachment_link($image, 'large')?>" alt="Projects" />
  </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```